# What are differences between stack- and register-based virtual machine's bytecode commands?

Tags: stack, registers, virtual-machine

What are differences between stack- and register-based virtual machine's bytecode commands?

For example [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)) has stack-based virtual machine.

But [Lua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)) has register-based vm.

So, what are the differences between bytecode commands?

Comment: I rewrite my question. Maybe now it is more focusing. (Sorry for my english)

Comment: Maybe this question should be rephrased to be a pro/con on stack vs registers?

Comment: Stack and registers are machines and ISAs features. Why are you asking about VMs in particular?

Comment: The last edit was too much in conflict with the original question and invalidated the existing answer; if the author wants to ask that question it's probably ok, but we shouldn't change it underneath them or add commentary to that extent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Register-based VMs (most often) need a way to specify operand registers for each instruction (i.e. `add rax, rbx`), while stack-based VMs get away with operating on the top of the stack (i.e. `add` just takes the pops the two stack items and pushes the sum back). I know that Python's bytecode also includes some convenience instructions to, for example, duplicate the top of stack, or to rotate the top three stack items around (`DUP_TOP`, `ROT_THREE`, and there's more like this). *(EDIT: I've just checked, and they appear to have been replaced with a more general `COPY(i)` and `SWAP(i)` in Python 3.11)*. A register-based VM would have no real need for these, since they can be easily expressed through register manipulations without any observable performance hit